# What does the Bell do?

Tags: story-of-seasons

*ringle ringle ringle*. Nothing seems to have happened. What does the bell do? The description says:

```
A bell you can use to herd animals. It's useful for 
taking them out to graze, or calling them back.
```

Well, I tried using the bell to both call my livestock in *and* send them out, with zero success.

How do you use the bell?

Comment: If it works like in previous games, you can't walk too far away from them, it basically just brings them closer to you. So you can't, say, be outside and them inside.

Comment: that sounds incredibly useless.

Comment: Harvest Moon: A New Beginning had a separate bell that was placed as an object, and this bell allowed you to send your animals out or call them in without pushing, which sounds like what you want.  Hopefully this game did not remove that, but I have no idea how to get the blueprint.